# want to to convert on click to on hover jquery autocomplete

Tags: jquery, html, css, autocomplete

i am using this code which is working correctly on click, but i want to use it on hover.

Kindly help me, thanks in advance.

ignore this text just to bypass the rules. ignore this text just to bypass the rules.

**Code.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>jQuery UI Autocomplete - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script>
  $(function() {
    var availableTags = [
      "ActionScript",
      "AppleScript",
      "Asp",
      "BASIC",
      "C",
      "C++",
      "Clojure",
      "COBOL",
      "ColdFusion",
      "Erlang",
      "Fortran",
      "Groovy",
      "Haskell",
      "Java",
      "JavaScript",
      "Lisp",
      "Perl",
      "PHP",
      "Python",
      "Ruby",
      "Scala",
      "Scheme"
    ];
    $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
      source: availableTags
    });
  });
  </script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="ui-widget">
  <label for="tags">Tags: </label>
  <input id="tags">
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: this is just copied and pasted from the [jQuery source code](https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#custom-data)...please post what youve tried

Comment: what is input type? is it text or button or what?

Answer (score 0):

for Hover, you need to do following

```
 $( "#YourField" ).hover(function() {

  });
```

Comment: Check in your browser what is the id of autocomplete elements wrapper. Then do something like this $("#YourTextBox").val($("#wrapper>element class").html())

Comment: this is the code of my input box <input type="text" name="s_city" class="h_input_two" id="tags"  placeholder="Select City">

Comment: And u want when your input get focus and it opens up autocomplete then you should be able to select options through keyboard. Am I right?

Comment: yeah i want it, Kindly help.

Comment: but you code(where you copied it) does do that. what exactly are u asking?

Comment: no i have tried to do myself, but i d not have sufficient command on jquery, therefore i am saying to help me.